# Is there a way to vectorize a matrix within dplyr?

Tags: r, vectorization, dplyr

I apologize that this is in no way a reproducible example, I would need to include 8+ functions and 400+ lines of code to get us there. Hopefully my question does not require all the details.

I have attached a dataset and some code below.

```
ConvSix<-structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L), .Label = c("1657", "1659", 
"1660", "1663", "1664", "1667", "1668", "1671", "1672", "1673", 
"1674", "1675", "1676", "1679", "1681", "1682", "1686", "24179", 
"24182", "24189", "24195", "24198", "24199", "24216", "30761", 
"30765", "30767", "30768", "30773", "30774", "30775", "30778", 
"30780", "30788"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), doy = c(176, 177, 177, 178, 179, 
181, 181, 181, 181, 182, 199, 199, 174, 174, 174, 194, 194, 194, 
195, 195, 182, 186, 186, 187, 187, 194, 194, 195, 195, 195), 
    Longitude.coa = c(-1918623.92988816, -1915625.6117173, -1912011.57125755, 
    -1909094.252066, -1909094.252066, -1912339.29567134, -1912339.29567134, 
    -1912429.93169228, -1912485.94778727, -1909380.68827563, 
    -1915763.37476112, -1915658.53714314, -1916374.81573586, 
    -1915667.07531997, -1912011.57125755, -1909094.252066, -1905336.63702012, 
    -1896846.27215507, -1905410.18958451, -1911926.51282942, 
    -1918760.23966444, -1919128.35996764, -1915653.62968484, 
    -1912011.57125755, -1909110.6223, -1918647.78803324, -1918676.48638926, 
    -1918737.25223137, -1918997.56988286, -1918926.10114947), 
    Latitude.coa = c(-294686.435954907, -297342.187723815, -296912.920136211, 
    -299162.031650183, -299162.031650183, -298125.747414955, 
    -298125.747414955, -298474.111957357, -298680.796517523, 
    -299588.651120501, -297734.757973053, -297665.020821887, 
    -296965.291264178, -297746.457230176, -296912.920136211, 
    -299162.031650183, -300214.429182455, -303207.371617076, 
    -300240.5574282, -297018.230650846, -294857.016860578, -295341.201667557, 
    -297698.276292234, -296912.920136211, -299186.406575262, 
    -294716.132690881, -294751.855761895, -294827.501570149, 
    -295163.932732639, -295062.645377488)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
test <- ConvSix %>% 
  group_by(ID, doy, Year) %>% 
  mutate(hr = homerange.custom(createDensity(NewFormLattice, PointPattern = as.matrix(ConvSix[,4:5]),
                                  k = 40, intensity = F, sparse = T), percent = 0.50, output = F))
```

The important part here is the `PointPattern` argument of the `createDensity` function. I think as written, this goes line by line through the ConvSix dataset to create homeranges. However, this is very slow, and I think it is using the entire length of the 4th and 5th columns rather than specific elements. For example, for the group ID = 1657, DOY = 177, and Year = 2018, the point pattern should only include the Lat and Lon values associated with that group. Based on this information, is there a more accurate notation for the `PointPattern` argument?

Another hopefully helpful example.

Imagine the below code

```
test <- ConvSix %>% 
  group_by(ID, doy, Year) %>% 
  mutate(hr = Latitude.coa*5
```

This would create a new column called hr that takes every row of the Latitude.coa and multiplies it by 5. This is the same function I want from the actual code, just a different end result.

EDIT:

```
createDensity <- function(formLatticeOutput, PointPattern=NULL, M=0.5, k,
                          intensity=FALSE, 
                          sparse=TRUE)
{
  #
  if(class(formLatticeOutput)!="formLatticeOutput"){
    stop("Should be the output from the function formLattice")
  }
  if((M == 0)|(M == 1)){warning("Setting M to zero or one is ill-advised")
  }
  init_prob <- addObservations(formLatticeOutput, PointPattern)
  p0 <- as.vector(init_prob$init_prob)
  if(!is.null(PointPattern)){PointPattern <- as.matrix(PointPattern)}
  poly_area <- areaRegion(formLatticeOutput)
  n <- length(PointPattern[,1])
  T<-makeTmatrix(formLatticeOutput, M=M, sparse=sparse)
  EW_locs <- formLatticeOutput$EW_locs
  NS_locs <- formLatticeOutput$NS_locs
  nodes <- formLatticeOutput$nodes
  z <- Tkp(T, k=k, p=p0)
  N <- length(NS_locs)*length(EW_locs)
  long <- rep(NA,N)
  if(intensity){
    long[as.numeric(rownames(nodes))] <-
      n*z*length(z)/poly_area
  }else{
    long[as.numeric(rownames(nodes))] <-
      z*length(z)/poly_area
  }
  densityOut     <- list(EW_locs = formLatticeOutput$EW_locs,
                         NS_locs = formLatticeOutput$NS_locs,
                         nodes = formLatticeOutput$nodes,
                         boundaryPoly = formLatticeOutput$poly,
                         hole_list = formLatticeOutput$hole_list,
                         PointPattern = PointPattern,
                         probs = z,
                         densityOut = long,
                         area = poly_area)
  class(densityOut) <- "densityOut"
  return(densityOut)
}
```

```
homerange.custom <- 
  function(densityOut, percent = 0.50, output=FALSE){
    #
    if(class(densityOut)!="densityOut"){
      stop("Should be the output from the function createDesity")}
    nodes <- densityOut$nodes
    poly <- densityOut$poly
    area <- densityOut$area
    z <- densityOut$probs
    cmstz <- cumsum(sort(z))
    count <- sum(cmstz <= (1-percent))
    ind <- (z>sort(z)[count])
    plot(nodes,cex=0.1)
    points(nodes[ind,],pch=19,cex=0.5)
    lines(rbind(poly,poly[1,]))
    #
    #  Compute proportion of total area in homerange
    #
    proportion <- sum(ind)/length(nodes[,1])
    prop.area <- proportion*area
    
  }
```

Comment: Formulate a simpler problem that does not require all those functions.

Comment: The functions `homerange.custom` and `createDensity` are the relevant code to produce, not the dplyr functions. They are what will determine whether it runs slowly and whether it is going line by line or if it is vectorised as you said.

Comment: @CalumYou I have added the two functions